How to change the Country on my Apple account
I sold my house with my apple devices (as they were being used for home automation).  Now I am in a different country.  I would like to change my Appleid's country.
When I click on Country / Region under Personal Information, it tells me

Your country or region can’t be changed right now.

When I read the help linked to it, the only two items that relate to me are

Subscriptions (which I have deleted)
Possessing a payment method for the new country (which I do)

And it suggests that I should enter a new payment method.

I tried changing the payment method.  The old card had expired anyway.

I entered card details from the new country
I entered the relevant address and phone number for the card
I copied this to the billing address
I pressed Update

And it tells me that the card is invalid for the old country....  Catch 22

Is there a way to Change the Country/Region?
I have read the old posts here on this topic.  They are either very old and the instructions don't correspond to the current menu on https://appleid.apple.com/ or they don't have an answer.
For example, one of them suggests that you cant change it until you add store credit.  But Apple's help says the reveres is true.  I have no store credit.

Can you change the payment method to "None" and then change the region?

Is this https://support.apple.com/en-au/118283 (or equivalent for your country) what you have followed? Note that deleting subscriptions is not sufficient - you must wait for them to expire.  What do Apple Support say?

@Gilby, yes thats what I followed.  But what I missed, as you pointed out, is that the subscriptions have to expire.  Thats a tad difficult to check now as I have deleted them.

I had not read the Apple blurb carefully.  I had deleted the subscriptions.  But as @Gilby pointed out, one has to wait for them to expire as well.
